# Why does a text content inherit the CSS from a previous span tag?

Tags: html, css, inheritance

I got this HTML:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-6">
     **<h1 id="primerbeneficio">Conoce a tu <span>lomito<span/> ideal</h1>**
       <button id="descargaapple" type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-      apple"></i> Download</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
       <img src="images/iphone6.png" class="title-image" alt="iphone-mockup">
    </div>

</div>
```

And I just want to modify the word "lomito", but in my page also is affected the next word "ideal" with the same style.

The console shows this:

[image]

As it seems, another span tag involves both words, and "ideal" inherits somehow from h1.. but obviously my html doesn´t intend that.

I got bootstrap 5 with a CDN, but that shouldn´t be a problem, or is it?

I´ve already tried changing the html, but it can´t go any further than that, I mean, is just a tag..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the following line which is causing the `span` tag to not close properly:

```
**<h1 id="primerbeneficio">Conoce a tu <span>lomito<span/> ideal</h1>**
```

It should be this:

```
<h1 id="primerbeneficio">Conoce a tu <span>lomito **</span>** ideal</h1>
enter code here
```

Notice where the `/` is. In your original markup since the `span` tag around the word "Lomito" wasn't closed properly. So your typo was interpreted by the browser to be another `<span>` tag which it then closed around the word "Ideal" which then the original `<span>` that comes before the word "Lomito" was then closed by the browser.

Fix the typo and it should appear as you intended it to be.

Also I would strongly advise if your using an editor that can install extensions to get one that auto-closes the tag for you. You'll avoid these types of issues in the future if you do so.

Comment: wooow that was quick Alex, this is my first question about development ever haha, I´m not glad that it was for quite a dumb error, but at least I know this works properly. Thank you good man :)

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly, you are targeting all spans within a h1**

You might be looking for the direct child selector `>` over the descendant selector   (space).

Your CSS selector would change from `h1 span` to `h1>span`

**Secondly, [`font-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style) is an inherited property**

This means that any descendant of an element you've set a font style on will inherit the same font style even if you target a direct child.

So the best solution is to just restyle the span in question, you could do it like this:

```css
.lomito span {
  font-style: revert;
}
```

revert is default element styles for your browser, you could also use initial for default property value

Comment: Thanks for the help man, it was just a silly typo haha, but I´ll take it into account in the future. Greetings